# What's the purpose of the mview_state table in the database?

Tags: magento2, database, index

I saw the numbers increasing in the **mview_state** table in the database and there is no cleanup.

[image: Magento 2 mview_state]

So I wonder what's the purpose of this table and the values that we have there?

Answer (score 0):

`mview_state` is a table enabling your indexes to feed their index tables.
That is the nutshell. Now, I have built a small dummy module with `index` this week.

the index file is as follows: `(etc/indexer.xml)`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
        <indexer id="cart_log" view_id="mbs_cart_log" class="Mbs\AdminScreen\Model\Indexer\CartLogCreator">
            <title translate="true">Cart Log Data</title>
            <description translate="true">Create Cart Log data</description>
        </indexer>
    </config>
```

there is a mview file `(etc/mview.xml)`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Mview/etc/mview.xsd">
    <view id="mbs_cart_log" class="Mbs\AdminScreen\Model\Indexer\CartLogCreator" group="indexer">
        <subscriptions>
            <table name="quote" entity_column="entity_id" />
        </subscriptions>
    </view>
</config>
```

The index is highly reliant on this `mview` file. The latter dictates that when a quote record is created, the entity_id is eventually stored in _cl table.

I will now describe where this _cl table comes from. In my module, my index table is `mbs_cart_log`. Magento will create a table called `mbs_cart_log_cl` as soon as your indexer is successfully registered. And this is the table that gets a record when the new quote record gets created. Also, an additional mview_state record will be created with the name of your view_id (the one in `/etc/view/xml`)

Once you have this working, then you just have to run the index you have just added, and you will see `mview_state` table being updated with a *version id* that matches the *_cl table latest record*.

Finally, but not least, your index table will contain the records that the indexer function `executeFull` will have extracted (mine is at \Mbs\AdminScreen\Model\Indexer\CartLogCreator::executeFull)